# Tomcat 6 Memory Consumption

Tags: tomcat6

Tomcat memory is keep on increasing for every minute. Currently Max limit is set as 1024 MB. If i increase the max limit then Tomcat is not starting. Please let mw know is there any way to reduce Memory usage for Tomcat.

Comment: Any one please put some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, when you say max limit, it means you have set maximum heap size (i.e., **-Xmx1024M**) as one of your options in catalina.bat.

It may be that your machine does not have enough RAM, and hence with a higher value of heap size, Tomcat fails to start (or other processes are running and hence Tomcat does not gets enough memory to start up).

With 1GB (the value you currently have), set below flags as well to have more information when the server goes out of memory and to enable concurrent garbage collection :
**-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError**

Also, **'jvisualvm.exe**' is the best way to start analyzing your server as to where actually memory leak is.